# Manipulate html inline cssclass with style attribute in .net

Tags: .net, css

I have 1 string contaning html and one string contaning css is there any way to remove all class attributes with style attributes based on the rules in the css string.

The reason i have for doing this is that i want to send the html as mail but gmail does not support style or link tags so my only option left is to use the style attribute but i would rather not bloat my html with the style attribute, is there any .net component out there that does this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after looking around i found the following 3 resources

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20450/Simple-CSS-Parser
2. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
3. http://forums.wincustomize.com/322441

By combing those i managed to complete the task!

Answer (score 0):

No, .net cannot help you with this. You should make a separate mail template and use inline styles for everything and use a table-based layout. Tweaking browser-oriented HTML/CSS for email use is asking for trouble. Even if you could automatically transfer the stylesheet to inline styles, many of the style declarations themselves **are not supported** by various clients anyway. You need an email-specific design, period.

Email clients greatly vary in abilities, forcing a terrible common denominator as if it's still 1999. MS Outlook even uses the brain-dead MS-Word rendering engine to view HTML emails. It's all a deep pit of awful.

Here's a good guide for how you can format emails: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/